# Do the choices made in The War Within affect the rest of the game?

Tags: warframe

During The War Within, you are given a few different choices, each with an alignment (for lack of a better word) attached to it. Do these choices affect anything in the game other than the quest's cutscenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, no.  As of this writing, the only effect that alignment has is in the cutscenes.  It is planned to be used more in the future, but it is not clear for what exactly.